# jquery doesn't detect a change event in text boxes for fractional value changes?

Tags: jquery, textbox, numbers, decimal, onchange

I am using jQuery and created a change listener on some text boxes that hold numeric values with 2 decimal places, if the integer part is changed then an event is triggered, if one of the decimal values changes nothing happens.

Is there a way to detect changes in the fractional portion of the number in a textbox?

Comment: You need to post code you are using

Comment: Joey, please share your JQuery and html markup. Much easier to comment on specific use cases.

Comment: Yes, what type of input are you using? If it's just a simple input with "type" set to "text" you could use the keyup event instead of the change event.